# Why Uber Deeplink not redirects to APPStore

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, uber-api

I am using [UBER deep link](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk).

The example working fine. But the problem is it's not redirecting to the app store (When the uber app is not installed)
Here is my tried code. -

```
let builder = RideParametersBuilder()

let rideParameters = builder.build()

let deeplink = RequestDeeplink(rideParameters: rideParameters, fallbackType: .appStore)
            deeplink.execute()
```